# Why does the special target .SECONDARY inhibits rebuilding targets?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a simply Makefile:

```
all: bootloader.bin

test.bin: test.o
    touch test.bin

bootloader.bin: test.bin
    touch bootloader.bin

test.o: test.c
    touch test.o
```

Everything works as expected when I delete `test.o` or `test.bin`. However if I add a `.SECONDARY:`-line after the `all:`-target-like it seems to break dependencies between all the targets. For example deleting test.o won't make it to be rebuilt when re-running make.

Why is that so? In my case .SECONDARY seems to remove the need for an intermediate target (.o and .bin) to be rebuilt independently whether a dependency non-existent anymore or not. That can't be useful, can it?

Answer (score 0):

From [GNU Makefile Special Built In Target Names:](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Targets.html)

*.SECONDARY with no prerequisites causes all targets to be treated as secondary (i.e., no target is removed because it is considered intermediate).*

So, in your case, all targets will be treated as `intermediate files`.

The loss of dependencies most likely has to do with the following two lines, taken from [Chains of Implicit Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Chained-Rules.html#Chained-Rules):

*Ordinarily, a file cannot be intermediate if it is mentioned in the makefile as a target or prerequisite.*

*When a file is secondary, make will not create the file merely because it does not already exist, but make does not automatically delete the file. Marking a file as secondary also marks it as intermediate.*